# how to improve cpu usage on Ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04, cpu, syslinux

I have two sessions running on Ubuntu 14.0x server, and I found that my program will take too long time to be finished. I used this instruction

```
root@ns3011857:~# top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | \
sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | \
awk '{print 100 - $1"%"}'
```

and found that the CPU usage is 21.3%.

How can I improve it to 100% or so; Is this dangerous for the server? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use `top` to give you this output, how about using it on its own to analyze which processes are running and spending CPU time?

Answer (score 0):

How about allocating priority to the process and increase its memory usage and 100% will slow down the other process execution

Execute the program in a terminal with a command line and  run `ps -ef`